# Join 2 different points in different images in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have 2 different images of same dimensions. There is 1 point of interest in each image. I want to join the 2 images by joining those 2 points in a plot with a line. How can I do that?
This is the rough idea of the image: http://i.imgbox.com/abhqL3XT.png

Comment: As in have the images side by side?

Comment: I mean the images are different matrices. I have the coordinates for the points.

Comment: Yes but you want to plot a line, so do you want to plot the images side by side or what? Post an example of the input and output (with the line) images?

Comment: Yes, I want to plot the images side-by-side. I tried to upload a picture, but my reputation score is not enough I think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's create two images

```
>> [X,Y] = meshgrid(-200:200, -200:200);
>> im1 = exp(-sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2)/100);
>> im2 = exp(-sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2)/200);
```

You can display them side by side with the `imagesc` command:

```
>> imagesc([im1 im2]);
```

[image]

Now say you want to connect two points in the images, with coordinates (100, 300) and (300, 50). Because the images are side by side, you need to add the width of the first image to the x coordinate in the second image:

```
>> width = size(im1, 2);
>> x1 = 100; y1 = 300;
>> x2 = 300 + width; y2 = 50;
```

Now you can put a `hold` on the image (so you can plot on top of it) and plot your line connecting the two points:

```
>> hold on;
>> plot([x1 x2], [y1 y2], 'r', 'LineWidth', 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this should do what you want:

```
% example random images (assumed gray-scale)
Img1 = rand(256)*.1;
Img2 = rand(256)*.3;

% widh of the images
imgWidth = size(Img1, 2);

%joined image
Img12 = [Img1, Img2];


% example points
[point1x, point1y] = deal(201, 100);
% point twos horizontal coordinate
% is shifted by the image width
[point2x, point2y] = deal(imgWidth + 101, 40);


% show images and plot the line
figure;
imshow(Img12);
hold on;
plot([point1x, point2x],[point1y, point2y], '+-b');
```